# metrics-server no metrics known for pod error during deployment

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, metrics-server

I have a newly created AWS EKS 1.18 Cluster, applications are deployed on it, everything is fine, test and load test are successful, namely, my HPA and metrics-server is working fine.

But when I make a deployment to a service, metrics-server is giving
`unable to fetch pod metrics for pod xxx: no metrics known for pod` for the newly deployed pod, then problem is being resolved and everything is fine again.

My question is, is this an expected behaviour for metrics-server? Or should I check my configs again?

Thank you very much.

Comment: There is a [comment](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/issues/299#issuecomment-550030920) about that on github, `Metrics Server is expected to report "no metrics known for pod" until cache will be populated. Cache can be empty on freshly deployed metrics-server or can miss values for newly deployed pods`. So if I understand correctly it's working as expected. I assume this problem is being solved after 60s? By default metrics are scraped every 60s.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jakub , yes it's being solved after a short amount of time. and I think so after your comment, it's working as expected

Comment: Happy to help. I have posted an answer with these informations. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted or upvote it as per [stackoverflow rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [comment](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/issues/299#issuecomment-550030920) about that on github:

> Metrics Server is expected to report "no metrics known for pod" until cache will be populated. Cache can be empty on freshly deployed metrics-server or can miss values for newly deployed pods.

So if I understand correctly it's working as **expected**. I assume this problem is being solved after 60s as by [default](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-often-metrics-are-scraped) metrics are scraped every 60s.